# Previewing Image in ASP.NET Image Control

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i want to preview an image as soon as it is uploaded. i am using ASP.NET FileUpload control and this is what i have done so far.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function callPostBack() {
        var uploadControlFileUploader = document.getElementById('<%=   FileUploadThumbnailImage.ClientID%>');
            var path = uploadControlFileUploader.value; alert(path);
            document.getElementById("ImageThumbnail").src = path;

            return false;


    }
</script>
```

when i run this code in localhost it works fine. but when i published it in iis it's not working. i want to do this using javascript. can anyone help me (ImageThumbnail is the ID of my preview button).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upload and preview image in client side without posting back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028727/upload-and-preview-image-in-client-side-without-posting-back)

Comment: thanx. it was realy helpful...

Answer (score 0):

you can get the solution from here-
[http://forums.asp.net/t/1740831.aspx/1?Preview+Image+before+upload+](http://forums.asp.net/t/1740831.aspx/1?Preview%20Image%20before%20upload%20)

and look into here too

[Upload and preview image in client side without posting back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028727/upload-and-preview-image-in-client-side-without-posting-back)